# Mac Terminal Process Complete Exit

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I'm on a Mac using the default Terminal to SSH into a remote Linux server.  When I idle long enough, I get the following message (see screenshot).

[image]

I can't seem to go back to typing commands unless I open a new window.  How do I exit the 'Process Completed' screen without closing the current window?  I tried the 'Send Reset' command and that didn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't! It is just waiting to exit and it isn't going to do anything else. The solution is probably to send Keep-Alives in your ssh session by adding

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

to your Mac's ssh config file.

I should add that the reason you get the [Porcess completed] message stems from the way you made the "ssh" connection in the first place - presumably by going to Terminal's "Shell" menu and selecting "New Remote Connection" or by changing Terminal's Preferences in the "Shell" menu tab to run ssh from there. If you just start a plain Terminal, and type your "ssh" command into the resulting terminal window and run it that way, if/when it times out, you can simply hit UpArrow and resubmit the "ssh" command without needing to start a new window.

Comment: Yep, I established the connection through Terminal's shell menu and selected "New Remote Connection" just as you guessed.